# How to handle structs/abstract data types in multiple files in C/SDL2

Tags: c, struct, sdl

I'm working on this graphics/game engine with SDL2 and C.

I manage to code all the basis for the game loop and I have things split in multiple files. A problem appeared when I tried defining my own data types (structs in this case). I have my struct *(vector3)* definition and declaration in **tad.h** and **tad.c**, but I'm having problems with creating variables with this *vector3* type. I tried declaring this **ponto1** in my main file, and I'm trying to use it in my other files as a global variable, but I'm getting some errors.

I want to be able to declare my own structs and pointers to structs, but I'm new to working in C with multiple files like this. Here are the files and problems I'm getting:
(PS: tips on how to structure better my program are welcome as well)

**tad.h:**

```
#ifndef TAD
#define TAD

typedef struct vector3 Vector3;

#endif
```

**tad.c:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

#include "./tad.h"
#include "./constants.h"
#include "./globals.h"

struct vector3 {
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;
};
```

**globals.h:**

```
extern SDL_Window* my_window;
extern SDL_Renderer* my_renderer;

extern int game_is_running;

extern Vector3 ponto1;
```

**main.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>


#include "./constants.h"
#include "./globals.h"
#include "./tad.h"
#include "./init_and_destroy.h"
#include "./setup.h"
#include "./process_input.h"
#include "./update.h"
#include "./render.h"

SDL_Window* my_window = NULL;
SDL_Renderer* my_renderer = NULL;
int game_is_running = FALSE;

Vector3 ponto1;


int main() {
    
    game_is_running  = initialize_window(&my_window, &my_renderer);
    
    setup();

    while(game_is_running) {
        process_input();
        update();
        render();
    }

    destroy_window(my_window, my_renderer);

    return 0;
}
```

**update.c**

```
#include "./constants.h"
#include "./globals.h"
#include "./tad.h"
#include "./update.h"

int last_frame_time = 0;

void update() {
    
    //caping frame rate
    int time_to_wait = FRAME_TARGET_TIME - (SDL_GetTicks() - last_frame_time);
    if (time_to_wait > 0 && time_to_wait <= FRAME_TARGET_TIME) {
        SDL_Delay(time_to_wait);
    }

    //delta time in seconds
    float delta_time = (SDL_GetTicks() - last_frame_time) / 1000.0f;

    last_frame_time = SDL_GetTicks();

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    ponto1.x += 20 * delta_time; //I'M TRYING TO ACCESS AND CHANGE THIS STRUCT

}
```

**The erros I get:**

```
./src/./globals.h:6:8: error: unknown type name ‘Vector3’
    6 | extern Vector3 ponto1;
      |        ^~~~~~~
In file included from ./src/main.c:6:
./src/./globals.h:6:8: error: unknown type name ‘Vector3’
    6 | extern Vector3 ponto1;
      |        ^~~~~~~
./src/main.c:18:9: error: conflicting types for ‘ponto1’; have ‘Vector3’ {aka ‘struct vector3’}
   18 | Vector3 ponto1;
      |         ^~~~~~
In file included from ./src/main.c:6:
./src/./globals.h:6:16: note: previous declaration of ‘ponto1’ with type ‘int’
    6 | extern Vector3 ponto1;
      |                ^~~~~~
./src/main.c:18:9: error: storage size of ‘ponto1’ isn’t known
   18 | Vector3 ponto1;
      |         ^~~~~~
In file included from ./src/process_input.c:4:
./src/./globals.h:6:8: error: unknown type name ‘Vector3’
    6 | extern Vector3 ponto1;
      |        ^~~~~~~
In file included from ./src/render.c:5:
./src/./globals.h:6:8: error: unknown type name ‘Vector3’
    6 | extern Vector3 ponto1;
      |        ^~~~~~~
./src/render.c: In function ‘render’:
./src/render.c:16:44: error: request for member ‘x’ in something not a structure or union
   16 |     SDL_RenderDrawPoint(my_renderer, ponto1.x, 50);
      |                                            ^
In file included from ./src/setup.c:5:
./src/./globals.h:6:8: error: unknown type name ‘Vector3’
    6 | extern Vector3 ponto1;
      |        ^~~~~~~
./src/setup.c: In function ‘setup’:
./src/setup.c:11:11: error: request for member ‘x’ in something not a structure or union
   11 |     ponto1.x = 3;
      |           ^
In file included from ./src/update.c:5:
./src/./globals.h:6:8: error: unknown type name ‘Vector3’
    6 | extern Vector3 ponto1;
      |        ^~~~~~~
./src/update.c: In function ‘update’:
./src/update.c:26:11: error: request for member ‘x’ in something not a structure or union
   26 |     ponto1.x += 20 * delta_time;
      |           ^
make: *** [Makefile:2: build] Error 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting an error because globals.h uses the type `Vector3` but that type hasn't been defined at that point.

You need to `#include "tad.h"` in globals.h since it uses types defined there.

The other problem you're seeing is because in files where tad.h is included and it uses fields of `Vector3`, the struct that the type refers to has been *declared* but not *defined*.  You need to move the struct definition out of tad.c and into tad.h so other files can use it.

Comment: Thank you! That completely solves my problem